# Is there a way to get access to Windows environment variables in wsl?

Tags: environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was thinking of adding something like this to my setup.bash script.

```
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/Ryan/Downloads $HOME/Downloads
```

But obviously that isn't always an accurate path so I was hoping to be able to do to *something* like

```
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/Downloads $HOME/Downloads
```

or

```
ln -s %USERPROFILE%/Downloads $HOME/Downloads
```

I know that obviously Windows % vars wouldn't work in bash but it would be cool if wsl could/does export those vars as `$Win32.HOME` or `$Win32.USER` or something.

Any thoughts?

Is there any way to do this already?

Answer (score 16):

Remembering that it's a shell's job to evaluate environment variables, and since you can invoke Windows exe's from within Linux on WSL, you can ask a Windows shell (Cmd or PowerShell) to expand out a Windows env-var. Here's how you'd do that with Cmd:

```
$ cmd.exe /c echo %username%
richturn
$
```

Alternatively, you can choose to [project some of your Windows environment variables into WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) if you prefer :)

Comment: Cmd.exe was not on my WSL path, so I first had to check your link and now it seems to work.

Comment: By default, WSL appends the Windows path to the Linux path, allowing you to execute any .exe on your Windows path from your Linux command-line (just be sure to specify the .exe extension - `cmd` alone won't work!). More on how to configure this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#wslenv-flags

Comment: Sadly, if you use `sudo su` to become root, the `$PATH` you then have *doesn't* have the Windows path appended, so you'll need to type out the full folder path to use `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of WSL2, which I believe have been backported to Win10 1903 and 1909, along with 2004, Microsoft introduced an environment variable `WSLENV` that is shared between Win32 and WSL to accomplish **exactly what you're after**.

You set it equal to a colon-seperated list of variables, together with some syntax to trigger path conversion, and whether the variable should be shared bi-directionally, or whether it should only be shared from Win32-->WSL2 or WSL2-->Win32.

For your specific use-case, on Win32 set `WSLENV=USERPROFILE/p`. That will trigger the Win32 env variable `%USERPROFILE%` to be passed to WSL (and back to Win32 if you call `cmd` or similar once you're in WSL), and to perform path translation.

Now in your `setup.bash` script, you can do

```bash
ln -s $USERPROFILE/Downloads $HOME/Downloads
```

For the various syntax of this functionality, see the Microsoft article
[Share Environment Vars between WSL and Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/).

Comment: there's a typo in your post - you've put "Win10 1093" instead of 1903.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did:

Since WSL now has interop between windows and WSL, I took advantage of that.

I have a powershell script in my `~/` folder called `~/.env.ps1`

```
# Will return all the environment variables in KEY=VALUE format
function Get-EnvironmentVariables {
    return (Get-ChildItem ENV: | foreach { "WIN_$(Get-LinuxSafeValue -Value ($_.Name -replace '\(|\)','').ToUpper())='$(Convert-ToWSLPath -Path $_.Value)'" })
}

# converts the C:\foo\bar path to the WSL counter part of /mnt/c/foo/bar
function Convert-ToWSLPath {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Path
    )
    (Get-LinuxSafeValue -Value (($Path -split ';' | foreach {
        if ($_ -ne $null -and $_ -ne '' -and $_.Length -gt 0) {
            (( (Fix-Path -Path $_) -replace '(^[A-Za-z])\:(.*)', '/mnt/$1$2') -replace '\\','/')
        }
    } ) -join ':'));
}

function Fix-Path {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Path
    )
    if ( $Path -match '^[A-Z]\:' ) {
        return $Path.Substring(0,1).ToLower()+$Path.Substring(1);
    } else {
        return $Path
    }
}

# Ouputs a string of exports that can be evaluated
function Import-EnvironmentVariables {
    return (Get-EnvironmentVariables | foreach { "export $_;" }) | Out-String
}

# Just escapes special characters
function Get-LinuxSafeValue {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Value
    )
    process {
        return $Value -replace "(\s|'|`"|\$|\#|&|!|~|``|\*|\?|\(|\)|\|)",'\$1';
    }
}
```

Now that I have that, in my `.bashrc` I have something like the following:

```
function winenv() {
    echo $(powershell.exe -Command "Import-Module .\.env.ps1; Import-EnvironmentVariables") | sed -e 's|\r|\n|g' -e 's|^[\s\t]*||g';
}

eval $(winenv)
```

---

A caveat to this, that I have found, is that I had to put the full path to `.env.ps1` in that command. What I did for that was wrote a function that converts the wsl style path back to the windows path. Then used that to translate it.

`CMD_DIR=$(wsldir "/mnt/c/Users/$USER/AppData/Local/lxss$HOME/\.env.ps1")`

because this is the function that loads the environment variables, I have to hard code the full path, to some extent. I did end up actually setting an environment variable in bash called `LXSS_ROOT=/mnt/c/Users/$USER/AppData/Local/lxss` and then used that.

---

Then, when I start a new shell, and I run `env` I get the following:

```
WIN_ONEDRIVE=/mnt/d/users/rconr/onedrive
PATH=~/bin:/foo:/usr/bin
WIN_PATH=/mnt/c/windows:/mnt/c/windows/system32
```

and I can now add something like `ln -s "$WIN_ONEDRIVE" "~/OneDrive"` to my `.bashrc`

For your example, you would do this:

```
ln -s $WIN_USERPROFILE/Downloads $HOME/Downloads
```

---

Additionally, I then created a script in my bin path called `powershell`.

```
# gets the lxss path from windows
function lxssdir() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        if echo "$PWD" | grep "^/mnt/[a-zA-Z]/" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            echo "$PWD";
        else
            echo "$LXSS_ROOT$PWD";
        fi
    else
        echo "$LXSS_ROOT$1";
    fi
}

PS_WORKING_DIR=$(lxssdir)
if [ -f "$1" ] && "$1" ~= ".ps1$"; then
    powershell.exe  -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "Set-Location '${PS_WORKING_DIR}'; Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Content $1))) ${*:2}"
elif [ -f "$1" ] && "$1" ~!= "\.ps1$"; then
    powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "Set-Location '${PS_WORKING_DIR}'; Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Content $1))) ${*:2}"
else
    powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy ByPass ${*:1}
fi
unset PS_WORKING_DIR
```

So I can then do something like this:

`$ powershell ~/my-ps-script.ps1`
`$ powershell -Command "Write-Host 'Hello World'"`

I am sure there are improvements that can be made to all of this. But, it is currently working for my scenario.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/camalot/2efbd85fd58753fc1a6aa90c3ff0f5a7) of the scripts I use.

Comment: Did you check the link of Rich regarding the `WSLENV`?

Answer (score 2):

Reviving this old post with this simple bash function I decided to add to my /etc/bash.bashrc

```
winenv()
{
  if [[ "$#" -eq 0 || "$1" == "--help" ]]
  then
    echo $'\n'"Usage:"
    echo $'\t'"winenv [-d] WINDOWS_ENVIRONEMENT_VARIABLE_NAME"
    echo $'\t'"-d: Defines environment variable in current shell"
    echo $'\t'"    Note that paths will be translated into un*x-like paths"$'\n'
    return
  fi
  local IFS='$\n'
  local PATH_TO_TRANSLATE=$1
  [[ "$1" == "-d" ]] && PATH_TO_TRANSLATE=$2
  local VAR=$(2>/dev/null cmd.exe /c echo %${PATH_TO_TRANSLATE}% | tr -d '\r')
  local NEW=$(wslpath -u "${VAR}" 2>/dev/null || echo ${VAR})
  echo "${PATH_TO_TRANSLATE} = $(printf '%q' "${VAR}") -> ${NEW}"
  [[ "$1" == "-d" ]] && export "${PATH_TO_TRANSLATE}=${NEW}"
}

for EnvVar in 'USERNAME' 'USERPROFILE' 'USERDOMAIN' 'USERDNSDOMAIN' 'WINDIR' 'SystemDrive' 'SystemRoot' 'TNS_ADMIN' 'ORACLE_HOME' 'CLIENT_NAME' 'HOMEDRIVE' 'HOMEPATH' 'TMP' 'TEMP'
do
  winenv -d $EnvVar >/dev/null
done
```

Comment: Not really a linux guy so may be something simple, but, pasting your code verbatim into my `bash.bashrc`, `source`ing it, then opening a new console just hammers me with a bunch of: `'\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\scott'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.`

Comment: You are right, haven't been using it for years, and got the same problem (and some others as well). I updated the answer so it should now hide the warning and works also in ZSH.

Comment: Working great for straight string env vars, but seems to have issues with expandable env vars: https://imgur.com/a/u3rINsN . Any way to handle that?

Comment: Never seen this screen (left part), are you on Windows 11? Since Windows 10 always returns expanded variables, even when defined with vars inside it: A=TEST and B=%A%.B works fine in Windows 10...

Comment: Yep, that's Win 10x64. The screen on the left is a 3rd party Env editor named "Rapid Environment Editor". Screen at right is Ubuntu in WSL.

Comment: Looks like the problem originate from the way your 3rd party app handles environment variables. Since this script echo the content of the variable using cmd, if it gets expanded in cmd, it will work...

Answer (score 0):

rather old, but I find this very useful.

this changes dirs to your windows home directory:

```
cd `cmd.exe /c echo %systemdrive%%homepath% 2> /dev/null | tr -d '\r' | xargs -0 wslpath`
```

Comment: What about using %UserProfile% ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my `.bashrc` so I can reference my Windows user directory in a similar way to `$HOME`:

```bash
WIN_HOME=$(wslpath -au "$(cmd.exe /c 'echo %UserProfile%')")
```

This assigns `$WIN_HOME` to a value like `/mnt/c/Users/Ryan`. [This question](https://superuser.com/q/1113385/16275) discusses `wslpath` and other approaches.

You can optionally `export` the variable, but that's only needed if you're going to read this variable from subprocesses and not just directly in your shell.